# Delphi procedure: First instruction doesn't compile

Tags: delphi, declaration, procedure

I'm writing a Delphi app, in which I have a procedure to clear the form and reset it to its default state.

```
procedure ResetForm ();
begin
   edtG1.Text := ''; // Error occurs on this line, no matter what the instruction is.
   edtG1.Enabled := True;
   btnG1Check.Enabled := True;
   .
   .
   .
   .
end;
```

I've tried everything - that first line of code in the procedure doesn't compile, no matter what. I can't see any problem with the declaration of the procedure either.

Can someone please assist? My thanks.

I am trying to clear all the fields in the form, enable what has been disabled, etc. To reset it to its default state as it starts at the beginning of the program. I tried different code instructions on that first line (yes, edtG1 exists), other controls do exactly the same and all other instructions. I have tried renaming the procedure too, but to no avail.

Comment: The compiler doesn't play tricks with you or is angry - it precisely tells **what** is wrong and **where**. Read the details of **any** error/warning/info message and learn to interpret them. Additionally: if you would have the instruction `Exit;` then it would **not** yield a syntax/compiler error.

Comment: Ignoring the content of error messages is a habit you must shake off

Comment: You say *doesn't compile* and *error happens here*, but you never once say what that error is, despite the fact that you get a clear, descriptive error message. When you write *an error*, the **very next thing to follow** should be the **exact, complete error message**. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us for help to solve **your** problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the details you have available.

Answer (score 5):

You have written a standalone routine and are accessing some controls which are on the form. That is not possible.

I assume you meant to write this as a method for your form.

Go to the interface section of your form unit, write `procedure ResetForm;` into the public section of your form class (where the comment `{ Public declarations }` is) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then write your code into the method.

Comment: *That is not possible.* Well, not strictly true. It is possible - using the forms reference, e.g. `Form1.edtG1.Text := '';`. But absolutely better as you suggest.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: But then you will (presumably) use the global `Form1` variable which, obviously, points to a single instance of the form (the auto-created one). If you in the future will create several instances of the form class, this will cause a nasty bug. On the other hand, using `Self` instead of `Form1`, in a method of the form class, will always give you the current instance, as expected. Of course Tom knows this, but I'm writing this for the benefit to others reading this Q&A.

Comment: It would have helped to give the actual compiler error in this question.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: In a procedure that is not a member of the form in question I would use the reference of the form, to address which forms `edtG1` I want to manipulate. Wheter it is `Form1` or `TheFormThatDealsWithWhateverData` is not relevant. `Self` is correct within the form, as you suggests, but the question was about a procedure that is NOT a member of the form, so it would not work.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Certainly. But to many readers of this SO page, `Form1` is the auto-created global variable that so many new Delphi developers have been misusing!

Comment: Whenever I see someone accessing these global form variables I get nausea attacks.

Comment: So, @Andreas, you are upset because I happened to use the autocreated form reference `Form1` in my example in my first comment above. Which is syntactically and functionally absolutely correct if that is the reference of the form. Everybody with more than hour experience of Delphi knows what `Form1` is. So why is that upsetting you? After all, your suggestion of using `Self` doesn't even work in the context at hand.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: I honestly have no idea what you are talking about. I was not upset at all, and I absolutely didn't think that you had misunderstood anything or that you are lacking in knowledge. I tried to make that clear by writing "Of course Tom knows this...". But I have too many times seen new junior devs using the auto-created global `FormN` variables (both in methods and stand-alone procedures) when they should be using `Self` or in some other way making sure that they are using the right instance of the form class. So my gut feeling was that the OP or some other new...

Comment: (cont.) Delphi developer would see this page and your comment and realise that `procedure ResetForm; Form1.edtG1.Text := ''` actually works, and so they will use that approach instead of making a method and using `Self`. And then the next week, they will not understand why the app starts to behave in a random fashion when they create five instances of the form class or a single one created dynamically etc. I am sorry if I offended you, but if so that was entirely unintentional. Written communication is difficult. The risk of misunderstandings is much greater in text.

Comment: That seems to have solved that part. My thanks.

Comment: These global form variables are the spawn of Satan and should be removed with extreme prejudice.